# Parsing a JSON Array using Gloss in Swift

Tags: json, swift

This is the JSON that I'm working with

```
data =     {
    error = 200;
    format = JSON;
    status = ok;
};
result =     (
            {
        connected = 1;
        id = 1;
        latitude = 0;
        longitude = 0;
        status = 0;
        "user_name" = Test;
    }
);
```

I'm using the library Gloss to parse this JSON, for the parsing the "data" I don't have any problem but when it comes to array like the "result" I have some troubles.

There are my structures :

```
import Gloss
import Foundation

struct Hoze_location: JSONDecodable {

    let data: Hoze_Data?
    let result: Hoze_result?

    init?(json: JSON) {
        self.data = "data" <~~ json
        self.result = "result" <~~ json
    }
}
```

And :

```
import Gloss
import Foundation

struct Hoze_result: JSONDecodable {

    let connected: Int?
    let id: Int?
    let latitude: Double?
    let longitude: Double?
    let status: Int?
    let user_name: String?

    init?(json: JSON) {
        self.connected = "connected" <~~ json
        self.id = "id" <~~ json
        self.latitude = "latitude" <~~ json
        self.longitude = "longitude" <~~ json
        self.status = "status" <~~ json
        self.user_name = "user_name" <~~ json
    }
}
```

There is my request I'm using Alamofire :

```
Alamofire.request("http://127.0.0.1:8081/user/location", method: .post, parameters: body, headers: myHeader).responseJSON {

        response in

        print(response.result.value)
        let my_data = Hoze_location(json: response.result.value as! Dictionary<String,Any>)
        print(my_data)
}
```

When I print "my_data" the Hoze_result is nil.

So if anyone have a clue of what I'm doing wrong, I'm opened to any solution you have.

Thank you in advance, Arkning.

Comment: Shouldn't `let result: Hoze_result?` be `let result: [Hoze_result]?`

Comment: rmaddy Thank you a lot ! I just tried it and it worked.